# Launch Fiori shell plugin before app component creation. How?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-cloud-platform

### Introduction

I am running a `testshell` project as "Shell plugin" in the **HANA Cloud Platform Fiori Launchpad**. When I visit the Launchpad in the default front page (with all the tiles), the shell plugin is loaded right.

My shell plugin modifies some things in the navigation URL's, so I **must ensure, that the shell plugin is loaded before the applications**' *Component.js* is loaded.

### Problem

But, when I start the Fiori Launchpad with a specific intent (for example https://HCP_URL/hrtest#requestleave-Display), the *Component.js* of the application **requestleave** is loaded first and then the shell plugins' *Component.js*.

From the documenation here https://help.hana.ondemand.com/cloud_portal_flp/frameset.htm?87764543e31247b5b471c06e3f6da6fc.html I read:

> When you launch SAP Fiori launchpad, all applications that are marked as shell plugin are initialized while the launchpad is loading.

How can I ensure, that the shell plugin is loaded and initialized before it creates Components for the given applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That the app is loaded before the plugin is actually intended behavior. The main take here is that loading a plugin should not slow down the FLP/Application startup. This is why app initialization is started before plugin initialization.
Currently there is no way to overcome this behavior.

Why do you require to manipulate the URL before starting the app? Please provide more information so that we I can perhaps come up with an alternative.

Comment: Ok, I think it is not possible to load a plugin before application.