# How to create a shell plugin app in SAP UI5/Fiori?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I want to create a shell plugin app to add additional functionality to my launchpad.
I referred to the following sap documentation https://help.sap.com/viewer/8422cb487c2146999a2a7dab9cc85cf7/Cloud/en-US/87764543e31247b5b471c06e3f6da6fc.html .
I want to know what exactly needs to be passed to the url parameter here ?
If somebody could give an example url of the shell plugin it would be great.

```
setInterval(function () {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "HEAD",
                cache: false,
                url: "the URL to the Component.js of the plugin"
            }).done(
                function (result) {
                    jQuery.sap.log.debug("pingServer", "Successfully pinged the server to extend the session");
                }
            ).fail(
                function () {
                    jQuery.sap.log.error("pingServer", "failed to ping the server to extend the session");
                }
            );
        }, 900000); //15 minutes
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fiori Launchpad HCP launch shell plugin before create component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41723015/fiori-launchpad-hcp-launch-shell-plugin-before-create-component)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to create a Fiori Launchpad Plugin, to enchance functionality to the Fiori Launchpad (FLP).

Such plugin will render within the FLP Shell container, the DOM object that represents the FLP. As one cannot determine when plugins are rendered, you can listen to approriate promise or events async in the init() function of the component.js in the plugin's code.

As with UI5 version 1.60, it is possible to create such a plugin from a template in the SAP WebIDE, if you have access to this cloud based IDE.
If so, check HELP/SAP.com for step-by-step description at https://help.sap.com/viewer/fb7108e0166c43d3900e8a609e129005/Cloud/en-US/ee0e48567c034991ac079eb93348d3b2.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing in the mentioned link is a sample code within Component.js which is used to ping the server every 15 minutes so that the user's session gets extended (does not timeout). That URL can be any working (not cached) link on your (Gateway) server.

Based on what you want as the additional functionality, you will be writing a completely different code within Component.js.